How to prevent opening RadWindow when come back via browsers back button?
In our .Net Framework app, there is a RadWindow inside master page to show notifications after login. IF there is any new notification that RadWindow opens. When it is closed it won't show again in that session. So DestroyOnClose property set as true. But when go to another page, and then come back to previous page by clicking brosers back button, that radwindow opens again. How to prevent that?
I have tried to hide it when DOMContentLoad, but it should be visible at first. Also tried hiding inside popstate event but it does not triggered when come back.

solution 1: your DestroyOnClose value changes on every page and you need to save the value temporarily on the session or any state management you want then check it when the document is attached to the window, this might help you [link][3]
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
console.log('User clicked back button');
});

solution 2: The hashchange event is triggered when there is a change in the fragment identifier (the part of the URL after the ‘#’) or when the URL itself changes. While not directly related to the back button, this event can be useful for tracking URL changes that may occur during navigation.
window.addEventListener('hashchange', event => {
console.log('Fragment identifier or URL changed');
});

I hope that solution helped you
